# type II$_1$ subalgebra of type III$_1$ factor

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Let $M$ be a type III$_1$ factor and $N$ be the type II$_1$ subalgebra of $M$.

What is the type of $N'\cap M$? Can it be any type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such a relative commutant $N' \cap M$ can even be any factor. Choose any type III$_1$ factor $P$ with a type II$_1$ subfactor $N \subset P$ with trivial relative commutant $N' \cap P = \mathbb{C} 1$. When $Q$ is an arbitrary factor, we get that $P \overline{\otimes} Q$ is a type III$_1$ factor that contains the type II$_1$ subfactor $N \otimes 1$ with relative commutant $1 \otimes Q$.

Comment: What is a good example to keep in mind of a type III_1 factor  with a type II_1 subfactor ⊂  with trivial relative commutant?

Comment: When $P_1$ is any type III$_1$ factor, one can realize $P_1$ as the crossed product of a II$_\infty$ factor $N_1$ and a trace scaling action of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $N_1$ is a type II$_\infty$ subfactor of $P_1$ with trivial relative commutant. Now take a projection $p \in N_1$ that is finite in $N_1$. Then $N = p N_1 p$ is a type II$_1$ subfactor of $P = p P_1 p$ with trivial relative commutant. The conclusion is that any type III$_1$ factor has a type II$_1$ subfactor with trivial relative commutant.